# How to get typeof generic interface

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

i am having

```
interface ITestInterface<TSource,TDestination>
```

i want the

```
void TestFunction(Type t1, Type t2)
{
    var x = typeof(ITestInterface<t1, t2>)
}
```

what is difference between genericMethod.Invoke(this, null)
and calling method direct i.e TestFunction(typeof(Emp), typeof(Dept)).
so that i can change function to

```
void TestFunction<TSource, TDestination>()
{
var x = typeof(ITestInterface<TSource, TDestination>)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `MakeGenericType` method to construct a generic type:

```
var x = typeof(ITestInterface<,>).MakeGenericType(t1, t2);
```

The first one (`typeof(ITestInterface<t1, t2>)`) is not valid because you are passing two *type instance* where the `type` is expected. They are not the same. Generics are statically typed, you can't specify a type instance as generic argument.

Comment: You need one comma to specify the type with _two_ type arguments.

Comment: you mean var x = typeof(ITestInterface<,>).MakeGenericType(t1, t2);